# How dangerous is to allow Google javascript?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, deanonymization, javascript, noscript

I know it's dangerous to allow javascript on some website. But very often if you want to register on a website you need to type captcha. If you want to see captcha you need to allow javascript from google and some more google affiliated websites. How dangerous is it ?

Comment: coveryourtracks.eff.org <br>
amiunique.org <br>
browserleaks.com <br>
jeffersonscher.com/res/resolution.php <br>
github.com/abrahamjuliot/creepjs <br>
github.com/arkenfox/TZP <br> welcome to the dark side